# TokyoTyrant - restart with clean datastore

Tags: tokyo-cabinet, tokyo-tyrant

What is the correct way to restart with a clean datastore with TokyoTyrant? Can it be done via the Linux command line?

I'm working on a project where I need to restart both TokyoTyrant and Solr in sync.

Comment: Can you clarify "clean" in your question? Do you mean "empty", "optimized" or something else?

Comment: I meant start over with a empty store. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete all records of your database
via tokyotyrant with the vanish command, e.g.

tcrmgr vanish [-port num] host